# http post - android application

Tags: php, android, servlets, http-post

I should make a connection to the server to fetch data from the database via php script using http post.
I am making an application for Android. 
Can you tell me a site where I can directly download the source code to try?

Answer (score 1):

I can provide a sample for you below.

This is the PHP code you need to get information from a database

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node
$response["products"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    $product["price"] = $row["price"];
    $product["description"] = $row["description"];
    $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
    $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];



    // push single product into final response array
    array_push($response["products"], $product);
}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Change the code to your needs

and then the code for android

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });

}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received 
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                TAG_NAME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

}